# Slice numpy array based on values of other array using more than 2 arguments

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

Here's my current code:

```
a = np.array(['apples', 'pear', 'oranges', 'grapes', 'apples', 'banana'])
b = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
my_list = ['apples', 'oranges', 'grapes']
```

How do I create a line of code that will return the following result:

```
result = np.array([1,3,4,5])
```

The method must use my_list as the basis for slicing array b based on array a.
(It should work regardless of the length of my_list)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you don't want to include `5` for apples in your output too?

Comment: oops! sorry my bad. edited it! 5 should be part. :) thanks!

Comment: What if `a = np.array(['oranges', 'apples', 'pear', 'grapes', 'apples', 'banana'])`. i.e. the items in `a` and not in the order of `my_list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slice using `np.in1d()`:

```
In [15]: b[np.in1d(a, my_list)]
Out[15]: array([1, 3, 4, 5])
```